# Oracles ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ODER BY ...) in HSQLDB

Tags: oracle, hsqldb, window-functions, in-memory-database

The project I'm working on has an Oracle 11 database which is accessed like

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.LOG_TIME ASC) rn,
        acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.LOG_TIME,
        acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.LOG_LEVEL,
        acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.MESSAGE,
        acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.CATEGORY,
    FROM acme_dept.LOG_TABLE
    )
    WHERE rn BETWEEN #{first_row} AND #{last_row}
    ORDER BY rn
```

That is the pattern used to paginate requests efficiently. This works perfectly fine in production.

Now I want introduce HSQLDB for unit tests. (Other in-memory DBMS would do as well. See below.) However, even when I create the schema with Oracle syntax compatibility mode `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;`, I get the following error message:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ORDER required: ) : line: 4 in statement [SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT row_number() over (
        ORDER BY acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.LOG_TIME ASC) rn,
        acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.LOG_TIME,
        acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.LOG_LEVEL,
        acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.MESSAGE,
        acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.CATEGORY,
    FROM acme_dept.LOG_TABLE
    )
    WHERE rn BETWEEN #{first_row} AND #{last_row}
    ORDER BY rn

//// stacktrace ommited ////
```

Is this some issue with HSQLDB? Just not implemented maybe.
Is there anything I can do about it?
Do any alternatives to HSQLDB have better Oracle SQL support?
Is there another pagination pattern, that is efficient in Oracle -- not only the LOG_TABLE got large over time -- and available in HSQLDB?
Or have I missed some point?

---

**Update:** Application is running on Oracle 11, unfortunately.

Comment: HSQLDB does not support window functions (no embedded DBMS does at the moment). If you are using Oracle 12 you can use `offset x
fetch first y rows only`. That works in HSQLDB as well. But you will stumble over many other little differences when doing this which makes (at least in my eyes) the tests pretty meaningless

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you've got the correct answer. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 12 you can use the ANSI SQL `fetch first x rows only` which works with HSQLDB as well:

```
SELECT acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.LOG_TIME,
       acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.LOG_LEVEL,
       acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.MESSAGE,
       acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.CATEGORY,
FROM acme_dept.LOG_TABLE
ORDER BY acme_dept.LOG_TABLE.LOG_TIME ASC
OFFSET #{first_row}
FETCH FIRST #{num_rows} ROWS ONLY
```

There is a difference to your existing code: you need to specify the number of rows to be fetch per page, not the absolute row number for the last row (that's why I changed `#{last_row}` to `#{num_rows}` in my example)

---

<sup>But in general I think it's a bad idea to use a different DBMS for testing then in production.There are too many subtle differences that make the tests futile in my opinion</sup>